# Change values from column in Power Query editor

Tags: powerbi, formatting, powerquery, reporting

I am working on a Power BI report and I am using a parquet file as the source. I have this column that holds info about the month:

[image]

As you see here, in MONTH_RUN, I have the data stored both as "202201" (yyyymm format) and "12/1/2021" (more like a date format).

I would need to change the values that appears like this: "12/1/2021" to "202112", so I can have all the values the same format.

I need to do this in a dynamic way, like searching for the rows that has values containing "/" character and based on that to change it into "yyyymm" format.

Is this possible?

I'm kinda new with power query and idk how should I implement this, but I would prefer to do it without creating any other additional columns.

Answer (score 1):

Please, do not post sample data as images. It makes it difficult to answer your question.

One way to deal with this is to [add a custom column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-add-custom-column), where the value will be either the same as `MONTH_RUN` (if it doesn't contain `/`), or it will parse the text to date, and then format it accordingly. For example:

```
if Text.Contains([MONTH_RUN], "/") then
    Date.ToText(Date.FromText([MONTH_RUN], [Format="M/d/yyyy", Culture="en-US"]), [Format="yyyyMM", Culture="en-US"])
else
    [MONTH_RUN]
```

[image]

Then use this custom column in your report.

Answer (score 0):

I would just delete the existing `MONTH_RUN` column and create a new one based on the date in the `DAY_RUN` column.

eg:

```
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"MONTH_RUN"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "MONTH_RUN", each Date.ToText([DAY_RUN],"yyyyMM"), type text)
```

Or, from the UI:

[image]